# How to cancel audio recording on run time in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing audio recording application in Android studio, everything is going good but I want to cancel recording at run time if user do not want to continue recording, when user click cancel button then recording should cancel and didt save in mobile device, any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to cancel recording at run time while saving in device. This is possible when we first store our file in database then into device, if file saves directly into device then it is not possible to cancel or rename at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this:

```
audioRecord.startRecording();

while (!isDestroy) {  // when isDestroy is true, recording will be cancel.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize]
    int readCount = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);// record

    if (readCount != 0 && readCount != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, readCount); // save to file , or play
    } 
}
 
audioRecord.stop();
audioRecord.release();
```